# Common variable from a R dataset in long format

Tags: r, data.table, dataset

I've a dataset with about 200000 rows with a structure similar to

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.frame(station = c(rep("A", 4),
                        rep("B", 2),
                        rep("C", 5),
                        rep("D", 3)),
                 variable = c(letters[3:6],
                        letters[3:4],
                        letters[3:7],
                        letters[3:5]),
                 numbers = rnorm(14)) %>%
                   data.table
```

I would like to store in a new vector the common `variable` repeated for each `station`. In this example the result should be `c d`, which are the common variables for stations A to B.

The number of the actual variable in the dataset is about 1000. I would appreciate a solution using the `data.table` syntax.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouped by 'variable', get the row index (`.I`) where the number of unique elements of 'station' is the same as the number of unique elements of 'station' in the whole dataset, extract the index (`$V1`) and subset the rows

```
unique(dt[dt[, .I[uniqueN(station) == uniqueN(dt$station)], variable]$V1]$variable)
#[1] "c" "d"
```

---

Or with `Reduce` and `intersect`

```
Reduce(intersect, split(dt$variable, dt$station))
#[1] "c" "d"
```